# terminate called throwing an exception (lldb) in Xcode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

`2013-06-21 06:34:17.023 richhh[3108:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x1dd2fa40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key banner.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32d6c2a3 0x3ac1797f 0x32d6bf99 0x335d91d9 0x335d4f2b 0x32cf261b 0x34d1131d 0x34d10b9b 0x34c0903d 0x34b9346d 0x34c1f353 0x34c60d11 0x34c5ffe7 0xd7fc3 0xd888d 0x34c5f0c5 0x34c5f077 0x34c5f055 0x34c5e90b 0x34c5ee01 0x34b875f1 0x34b74801 0x34b7411b 0x3687f5a3 0x3687f1d3 0x32d41173 0x32d41117 0x32d3ff99 0x32cb2ebd 0x32cb2d49 0x3687e2eb 0x34bc8301 0xd61b5 0x3b04eb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)`

What does all of this mean and how do I fix it? When I press my button, it pauses and shows this.

Comment: show ur code. or just check your xib if your object banner is not viewcontroller. just remove that in xib.

Answer (score 0):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key **banner**

Outlet in your Xib is referring to banner property, that does not exist.